# Remote servlet by mod_jk?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-jk

I have remote servlet for example: h*tps://[ip_address]/servlet (h*tps://[ip_address]/ - Tomcat main page) that i need to configure on local Apache HTTPd server. My mod_jk configuration looks like below, but doesn't work. Something works, because when i type h*tps://localhost/console in a browser i get Tomcat error page "HTTP Status 404 - /console/".

```
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
JkLogFile     /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    info
JkMount /console/* ajp13
```

workers.properties:

```
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.host=[ip_address]
worker.ajp13.port=8009
```

Remote Tomcat is configured good i think - listen on port 8009 and servlet h*tps://[ip_address]/servlet works too.

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" />
```

Anybody helps ?

Comment: You should switch to mod_proxy_ajp. It has a much cleaner syntax. mod_jk is buggy and deprecated.

Comment: al, mod_jk2 is buggy and depreciated, mod_jk is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern /console/* wont match /console.

Normally it's easiest to set up the JkMounts as

```
JkMount /console ajp13
JkMount /console/* ajp13
```

For debugging things like this it's very useful to increase the logging level, so set

```
JkLogLevel    debug
```

and have a read through the log you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is OK in the mod_jk.log ?

Could you try with

```
JkMount /console* ajp13
```

?